# MS Access: Error of +2 gb after splitting the file

Tags: ms-access

Sometimes (this is weird), my Access file finished with an error saying that the limit of 2 gb has been exceeded. I already splitted the file in frontend and backend, and the frontend has a size of 900 mb, approximately, and the backend of 500 mb. So the limit is not reached, and the disk has more free space:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnWFb.png)

If I delete the information of the backend before running the file, it works fine most of the time (not always). What could I do? Why does it say that the 2 gb is reached and I don't see it?

If it fails, it fails always in the same query.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your DB has lots of data that is being loaded into it on a continuous basis. MS Access creates shadow tables of this information in the file. This is what causes file bloat. You can drastically reduce your file size by doing the following...

To avoid bloat, you should have the front end perform a "Compact Repair" each time that the file is closed.

`File>Options>Current Database` and then Check `Compact on Close` in the first section. This way each time the DB Front End is closed it deletes the shadow tables Access created.

Also do a manual Compact & Repair on your backend as well (In `Ribbon Database Tools>Compact & Repair`). The backend is where the actual data resides, so it is likely to be larger than the front end, but 500MB of shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yes, I do a Compact and Repair before running the macro, and also when I close it. But it doesn't fix the problem. How can I manage those shadow tables?

Comment: If you're already doing C&R then things get trickier. You will need to start looking at the data that you are loading into your DB and whether you really need all of it. Just out of curiosity, I once had an extremely huge DB which turned out to be huge because images were stored in it. Do you have any high resolution images in your DB?

Comment: Nope. I load +30 txt that with an average size of 25 mb (i.e, the sum of the files is 700-800 mb)

Comment: Do you do any kind of data processing where you only keep the results? If so, you could load the txt files into a separate access db and then only import the finished results. Lastly, you could upsize to a ms sql backend.

Comment: How can I see the shadow files?

Comment: @Dylan You can do one thing. Create a new access file then import objects (table, query, forms, report etc) from your current file to new file.

Comment: @Dylan You can‘t look at them as far as i know. Which is why the compact repair function is needed.